# HG command path in TeamCity in Windows

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

I'm configuring my build server using TeamCity with Mercurial and I don't know what is "HG command path" field.

And the field "Pull changes from"? Should I put the address I'm cloning? From i.e. http://192.168.87.143/hg/TestProject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HG command path` is the path to hg executable on the server, put `hg` there if it is in the PATH. And yes, `Pull changes from` is for address of your repository.